# Receiving input from STDIN in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unix, io, stdin, netcat

I'm experimenting with GNU netcat's `-e` flag, which allows you to attach a program to a TCP socket so that it can send and receive messages with STDIN/STDOUT. I'm having some trouble writing a simple Ruby program that echoes it's input back to the client. Here is what I have now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

while line = gets.chomp do
    puts line
end
```

I can run this program as a server with this command: `nc -l -p 1299 -e ./chat-client.rb`. But if I connect to my server using `nc localhost 1299`, my communication looks like this:

Input:

```
I just don't know.
What is going wrong here?
```

Output after ^C-ing the server:

```
/chat-client.rb:3:in `gets': Interrupt
    from ./chat-client.rb:3:in `gets'
    from ./chat-client.rb:3:in `<main>'
I just don't know.
What is going wrong here?
```

If I ^C the client before the server, no output is given at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby may hold output in a buffer before writing to `STDOUT`, and write once an indeterminate amount of data has been printed. If you change your code to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

while line = gets.chomp do
  puts line
  STDOUT.flush
  # $stdout.flush works too, though the difference
  # is outside the scope of this question
end
```

You can expect to see the output before you close the input stream.

As for "^C the client before the server", closing the process immediately will disregard all of the data which has not yet been flushed.

Comment: _“Ruby only outputs to STDOUT once an indeterminate amount of data has been printed.”_ —strictly speaking this is not true.

Comment: Rephrased for accuracy/nitpicking ;)

Comment: I have deleted my answer, since yours contains a better explanation. Although, consider using `$stdout` over `STDOUT` since the former might be changed easily.

Comment: Or set `$stdout.sync = true` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Added a reference to `$stdout` for completeness' sake